# Line of sight integration of a field along a specific direction

Tags: numpy, integration

Good morning,
I have a *.npy file where I stored some variables, including OH which is the variable I would like to integrate over the line of sight in Z direction (I have a 3D field.)

I am new with working with such tools on non-netcdf files. Has someone an advice on how to perform the integration over the line of sight?

Comment: can you create a minmal working example with synthetic test-data?

Comment: I have a .npy file where I have variables stored like that: OH X Y Z. I have to access the file and perform a LOS integration along the Z axis and display the image I obtain.